# Problem importing CNTK in Azure jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, azure-ml, pip

Vineeth Sai indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316927/no-module-named-cntk) that with the following code:

```
pip install cntk
```

the problem is solved. However, I am getting the error shown in attached image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your latest edit in mind, the error in your screenshot is actually just a recommendation to upgrade `pip`. As suggested, please run `pip install --upgrade pip`, and it shall upgrade pip package in your environment and shall not re-appear unless a new version of pip get released later on.

Comment: It did not work, and so I asked the corresponding question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/43110/problem-upgrading-pip-command-in-azure-jupyter-notebook

Comment: In your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayg9c.jpg), I see that you've added an additional `!` before `pip install --upgrade pip`, which isn't required. If it still doesn't work, try `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` as well & share error screenshot if it fails. Please note that ideally pip upgrade won't impact CNTK installation but nevertheless it is a better idea to keep packages upgraded.

Comment: When I try with the  sudo pip install --upgrade pip  it asked me for a password nbuser. I insert my azure notebook password but it does not function

Comment: I have already tried without the !. I understand that I should be able to import CNTK even without upgrading pip. What I now discover is that is a problem with a particular notebook, because from other notebooks I can import CNTK without any problem.

Comment: If you're able to import CNTK in other notebooks, then it seems the notebook in question is being launched from some other directory where CNTK isn't installed. You may like to run `pwd` in Input cell of both the notebooks to be sure that those are getting launched from same directory (where CNTK is installed). Optionally, you may also like to refresh kernel for the notebook in question.

Comment: It was some problem with this specific notebook that I was not able to identify. I verified that it was on the right directory, but finally I substitute it with an equivalent file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
sudo pip install cntk
```

or:

```
sudo su [type admin password]
pip install cntk
```