# Problem upgrading pip command in Azure Jupyter notebook

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter, pip

Trying to install CNTK, I received a message saying that I should upgrade pip command [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/43068/problem-importing-cntk-in-azure-jupyter-notebook)

This one is another question related to the upgrading of pip.

After the installation with the command

```
pip install cntk
```

I received another error message as shown in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: Hi there! imho try Google for such queries as they are dependent on your personal machine..... The error means that it couldn't find the version for your platform.. try visiting the website of that package and check whether it's available...

Comment: Also you have **Permission error**, so just run in admin mode and it should go away :)

Comment: I have edited to question explaining that it is not a duplicate

Comment: @Aditya I have tried to run the admin mode using the Azure Notebook password but it did not accept it.

Comment: If you trying to install multiple libraries and upgrades at once, no need to use `install` flag again. If you give install again, it thinks it as a package installation named `install` and tries to fetch it, well it fails. The command general format `pip install library1 library2 --upgrade library3`, in this format. So root level if `PermissionError` pops up.